# WPF MVVM pattern ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

due to the mvvm pattern Model  shouldn't know anything about ViewModel.

What if I create a **ListBox** Field in one of my Model. Looks well and right.
But next step I have to tie this value to the ObservableCollection in ModelView.

I can do this:

var myCollection = new ObservableCollection (myList);

But in this case I lost of all advantages for OC. THis collection made static and neither inserts or updates reflects in my View tied to this collection.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
var myCollection = new ObservableCollection (ListBox)
```

You are copying the values of myList into the ObservableCollection.  Nothing here will update ListBox list.

If this is the desired effect, and you may want to update your ViewModel with:

```
///...
var myCollection = new ObservableCollection (ListBox)
myCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => RefreshListBox(myCollection);
///...
private void RefrehListBox(ObservableCollection<...> collection){
 //Refresh ListBox with collection
}
```

This way, every time the ObservableCollection updates, you synchronize the underlying model with the changes.

Comment: Nice way to sync ModelView to Model. But how about vice versa - updating ViewModel from Model ?

Comment: Well, you will probably need another event mechanism if you want it to work seamlessly that way.  You could use another ObservableCollection in the Model, or write your own events that the VM can listen to.

Answer (score 2):

You normaly use an ObservableCollection because it automatically updates the interfaces. I think you are doing something in a wrong way.
In your ViewModel you have the ObservableCollection with a list of elements, you can initialize it with a normal list o an array of elements. You shouldn't initialize your OC with your ListBox. After you have to bind it in your view.
When you add an element in you OC the view will update.

Comment: But I update myList in Model - no OC in View Model. Looks like I have to make my own event to update OC ?

Comment: If your Model doesn't have ways of signalling changes then yes - you'll need to invent something that will. Ie. have a VM method for adding elements that calls the underlying M method and also refreshes the ObservableCollection in the VM. Your ComboBox would be bound to OC on the VM.